# Writing text letter by letter with canvas JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the letters to write out one by one which it does but having more of a timeout when each letter is written. `setTimeout()` method does not work well since the upper part of the code is running in a update function and is getting called every frame.
Here is my code:

```
function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update); //Updates canvas every frame

    /**/ //Checking if the keys are pressed down and changes velocity accordingly
    if /*W & uparrow*/ (keys[87] || keys[38]) {
        if (velY > -speed) {
            velY--;
        }
    }
    if /*S & downarrow*/ (keys[83] || keys[40]) {
        if (velY < speed) {
            velY++;
        }
    }
    if /*D & rightarrow*/ (keys[68] || keys[39]) {
        if (velX < speed) {
            velX++;
        }
    }
    if /*A & leftarrow*/ (keys[65] || keys[37]) {
        if (velX > -speed) {
            velX--;
        }
    }
    /**/

    /**/ //Bullet bounds check
    if (bulletxc < (WIDTH + 40)){
        /**/ //Bullet moving if it is in frame
        if (bulletVelocity < bulletSpeed) {
            bulletVelocity++;
        }
        /**/
    } else {        
        bulletxc = 120; //Setting start position
    }
    /**/

    /**/ //Applies friction and move the character
    bulletVelocity *= bulletFriction;
    bulletxc += bulletVelocity;
    /**/

    /**/ // Applying friction so the character stops and moves according to the physics
    velY *= friction;
    y += velY;
    velX *= friction;
    x += velX;
    /**/

    /**/ // Checking for bounds On the x axis
    if (x >= (WIDTH - 78)) {
        x = (WIDTH - 78);
    } else if (x <= 3) {
        x = 3;
    }
    /**/

    /**/ // Checking for bounds On the y axis
    if (y > (HEIGHT - 120)) {
        y = (HEIGHT - 120);
    } else if (y <= 3) {
        y = 3;
    }
    /**/

    /**/ //Drawing the placeholder character
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    characterImg = document.getElementById('character');
    character = new createImage(characterImg, x, y, characterWidth, characterHeight);
    /**/

    /**/ //Drawing and setting collision hitbox for projectile
    bulletImg = document.getElementById('bullet');
    bullet = new createImage(bulletImg, bulletxc, bulletyc, bulletWidth, bulletHeight);
    var bulletx = bulletxc + (bulletWidth - 32);
    var bullety = bulletyc + bulletHeight;
    var combineX = x + characterWidth;
    var combineY = y + characterHeight;
    if((bulletyc<=combineY && y<=bullety) && (x<=bulletx && combineX>=bulletxc)){
        //alert("Collision Detected");
        bulletxc = 120;
        updateText();
        charHealthPoints += -1;
    }
    /**/
    let healthPointText = createText("black", pfont, "20px", "Health: " + charHealthPoints, 26, 36);
    let writtenText = createText("black", pfont, "50px", letter.join(""), 510, 100);
    if (charHealthPoints <= 0){
        window.open('death.html','_self');
    }
}
/**/
function increaseI(){
    i += 1;
}

function writeText(){
    letter[i] = text[i];
}

createText = function(fillStyles, fonts, fontsize, text, x, y) {
    ctx.font = fontsize + " " + fonts;
    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyles;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
};

function updateText(){
    requestAnimationFrame(updateText);


    writeText();
    increaseI();
}
```

How can I make it so that the letter sticks on the canvas without drawing the one by one manually?

Comment: Unrelated but why are you calling new here? It’s just a function.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know it worked before so i thought that was how you did it but apparently not.

Comment: could you post also the code of your update function? If you have a timeout in your update function maybe you can check the time which has passed since the last update cycle and call ```writeText``` only if the passed time is big enough. ```Date.now()``` gives you the current time.

Comment: Okay thanks i will try this and get back later. @flappix

Comment: also updated the post with entire update method

Comment: Do you mean somethign like this?
`var sixSec = 6000;
    if ((isDateCorrect - Date.now()) > sixSec){
        writeText();
        increaseI();
        isDateCorrect = new Date();
    }` @flappix

Comment: yes. do you need further assistance or is it working like this?

Comment: It did not work but it sorta works just having is as is even though i can't control the speed of the writing so its fine But thank you so much for all the help. @flappix

Comment: you can control the speed by the variable ```sixSec```